# Loop though table with no concurrent id

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that contain memberId's but they do not run concurrently.

How must I loop through them?

I have this:

```
 select mm.memberid, mm.aspnetuserid, mm.email
 into #MemberIdsToDelete
   from membership.members as mm 
   left join aspnet_membership as asp
     on mm.aspnetuserid=asp.userid 
   left join trade.tradesmen as tr 
     on tr.memberid=mm.memberid  
   where asp.isapproved = 0 and tr.ImportDPN IS NOT NULL and tr.importDPN <> ''
   order by mm.memberid

 ALTER TABLE #MemberIdsToDelete ADD id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT

 DECLARE @MaxRownum int
 SET @MaxRownum = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM MemberIdsToDelete)

WHILE @Iter <= @MaxRownum
 -- do things
 SET @Iter = @Iter + 1
END
```

The above is not correct, I get error on the alter table line obviously: 
Incorrect syntax near 'AUTO_INCREMENT'

Comment: Why do you need to loop through them row by row? What does `-- do things` entail? You should use set based operations in SQL if possible. Also You need `IDENTITY` not `AUTO_INCREMENT`. You can use `select IDENTITY(INT,1,1) AS ID, mm.memberid, mm.aspnetuserid, mm.email INTO ....` to do that in one operation.

Comment: Concurrent? Could it be you mean "continuous"?

Comment: i have to loop through each row to get the memberid, which is not sequential so I can delete from all other tables where the memberId matches.

Comment: non concurrent: 1,3,4,5,8,22. concurrent: 1,2,3,4,5,6, etc

Comment: You can do that set based rather than deleting one row at a time. `DELETE FROM SomeTable WHERE memberid IN (...)` etc. Also looks like you are just reinventing a cursor. To loop through all rows without requiring a sequential column you could just use a cursor.

Comment: That's "continuous". Concurrent means "parallel" or "at the same time".

Comment: @Martin Smith: thanks I tried that but how come ID starts at 73183 and my memberid is also not right it starts at 114848??

Comment: `IDENTITY(INT,1,1)` should start at `1` and increment by `1`. The code doesn't do any manipulation of `memberid` at all so no idea what you mean. BTW it is pointless doing a left join on `aspnet_membership as asp` then `where asp.isapproved = 0` as that where clause converts the join back to an inner join. Same issue for the other left join on `trade.tradesmen as tr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cursors to loop through table, something like this:

```
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT Col1, Col2, -- your select query 

OPEN db_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @Var1, @Var2, -- list of your variables based on select query

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN

    -- do stuff

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @Var1, @Var2, -- list of your variables based on select query
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Comment: You can, but you should not unless you absolutely cannot avoid it.

Comment: looks like this is what i need to do, my operation will be a once off, to clean out old records with all their references to other tables. there are about 14 tables affected and i have 180378 records..eish

Comment: @charlie_cat then it looks like this is not what you want to do. WHy do 2525292 things, when you can do 14. The database will work out how to best handle those 2525292 things

Answer (score 1):

`ALTER TABLE` changes the actual table, not the data. There's no point adding a column after you've added the data, so it probably isn't what you want.

You can loop through any result set with a cursor, but there are two important rules about cursors:

1. Never use a cursor when you can do a set operation.
2. You probably don't need a cursor for that thing you're thinking about, re-think for a while to be sure you need it. `CURSOR` is a sign that you are thinking about a SQL problem like it was a procedural code problem - it might be the only way, but avoid it (even do something else and come back after lunch if you don't see the set approach).

In the comments you say you need to delete from other tables, that would be much better dones as:

```
delete from table1 where memberId in
(
select mm.memberid
   from membership.members as mm 
   left join aspnet_membership as asp
     on mm.aspnetuserid=asp.userid 
   left join trade.tradesmen as tr 
     on tr.memberid=mm.memberid  
   where asp.isapproved = 0 and tr.ImportDPN IS NOT NULL and tr.importDPN <> ''
)
delete from table2 where memberId in
(
select mm.memberid
   from membership.members as mm 
   left join aspnet_membership as asp
     on mm.aspnetuserid=asp.userid 
   left join trade.tradesmen as tr 
     on tr.memberid=mm.memberid  
   where asp.isapproved = 0 and tr.ImportDPN IS NOT NULL and tr.importDPN <> ''
)
delete from table3 where memberId in
(
select mm.memberid
   from membership.members as mm 
   left join aspnet_membership as asp
     on mm.aspnetuserid=asp.userid 
   left join trade.tradesmen as tr 
     on tr.memberid=mm.memberid  
   where asp.isapproved = 0 and tr.ImportDPN IS NOT NULL and tr.importDPN <> ''
)
```

Three set based operations, which are inherently faster, are something the query analyser can do a better job of optimising for you, and which best of all, are simpler to write.

Answer (score 0):

maybe Row_Number() is more what you want + I've just relected a lot of the comments made to the OP:

```
    SELECT 
        IDENTITY(INT,1,1) AS ID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY mm.memberid) AS RowN,
        mm.memberid,
        mm.aspnetuserid,
        mm.email  
    INTO #MemberIdsToDelete    
    FROM 
        membership.members  mm     
        INNER JOIN aspnet_membership  asp      
            ON mm.aspnetuserid=asp.userid     
        INNER JOIN trade.tradesmen  tr       
            ON tr.memberid=mm.memberid      
    WHERE 
        asp.isapproved <> 0 
        AND tr.importDPN <> ''    


    DECLARE @MaxRownum INT  = (SELECT MAX(RowN) FROM MemberIdsToDelete)  
    DECLARE @Iter INT = 0

    WHILE @Iter <= @MaxRownum  
       -- do things  
        SET @Iter = @Iter + 1 
    END
```